# Testing for different types of hash values in Perl?

Tags: perl, validation, hash, xml-parsing

I'm writing a small Perl script that goes through an XML file via `XML::Simple`

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $detail= $xml->XMLin($xml_local);
```

Sometimes, the contents of an element in the XML are empty.

When there is no content in an element in the XML, and I try to print out the contents using:

```
print $detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents}
```

I get the output:

`HASH(0x18948c4)`

......or something similar..... the only difference is the chars between the ()'s

I want to test if the content is empty and default the variable to something else - maybe `''` or `""` - anything but the hash reference/address/whatever that is.

I tried this, but got an error that its not an array reference:

`print $detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents}[0]`

---

**UPDATE**

Output of one of the elements using `Data::Dumper`:

```
'something' => [
           {
             'somedetail' => '',
             'somedetail' => '',
             'somedetail' => 'http://www.google.com'
             'somedetail' => 'google',
             'somedetail' => '1',
             'somedetail' => '01/21/02'
           },
```

How can I test for these `''` empty strings using Perl?  They are returned as `HASH(0x18948c4)` unless some filtering is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it prints `HASH(0x18948c4)` is because the contents of that value are NOT in fact empty, but a hashref. When you print something, Perl tries to stringify that something, and stringified result of a hash reference is `HASH(address)` where address is the address of the actual hash.

Print the actual contents of that hashref as follows:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Data::Dumper->Dump([$detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents}]);
```

If as you say there are "no contents", it will probably be an empty hashref:

```
$VAR1 = {};
```

If so, you can check for it via:

```
if (ref($detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents}) eq ref({})
  && !keys %{ $detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents} })
    print "No contents, empty hashref";
}
```

First condition ensures it's a hashref, second, that the hash resulting from its dereference has zero elements as its keys - meaning it's an empty hash being referenced.

**However, I seriously doubt it's an empty hash** from what I recall about XML::Simple - and doing the Data::Dumper print as shown above will show you HOW to deal with it. You should always print out unknown data structures this way to figure out what to do with them.

E.g., if your Data::Dumper output was:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1
        };
```

Then you need to print `$detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents}->{a}`, obviously. Again, be careful to only print something that is a scalar and not an arrayref or hashref, so go down the data structure as much as needed to get to a scalar.

Comment: I did print out the data structure using `Data::Dumper` - the 'Element' => {content} results to `'Element'=>{}`

Comment: also, you are missing the first `{` before the print statement

Comment: I get an error for the if statement conditionals:  `Not an ARRAY reference at script.pl line xx.` - I'm going to try to take out the first part of the two tests

Comment: that gave me same error... but it works if i take the 2nd condition out - `if (ref($detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents}) eq ref({})`

Comment: the 'value' was `ref({})` - thanks... it works if i take out the second condition of the if statement

Comment: maybe the `&&` should be `||`?

Comment: No, this is wrong. "ref({})" has nothing to do with whether iy is empty, only if it's a hashref. Can you please print the results from `print Data::Dumper->Dump([$detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}]);` ?

Comment: @DVK - I have the output from `Data::Dumper` posted above

Comment: @CheeseConQueso - what was the parameter you gave to Data::Dumper? And what are you trying to detect again?

Comment: @DVK - I handed it the entire xml file - `my $detail= $xml->XMLin($xml_local); print Dumper($detail);`  I'm trying to detect those values that are `''`

Comment: @DVK - 2 more things: 1 - "somedetail" is arbitrary, not all the element details have the same name. 2 - the `''` values come back with the hash ref/address

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of DVK's answer that worked for me:

```
if (ref($detail->{Parsing}->{Through}->{XML}->{ElementContents}) eq ref({}))
{
    ...empty element content...
}
```

I needed to remove the 2nd condition of the `if(condition1 && condition2)` statement he gave me.

Comment: This only worked by accident. ref({}) doesn't check for emptiness, only for bveing ANY hashref. The value of ref({}) is a string 
"HASH".

Comment: i think i understand what you are saying, but when I run this through a foreach loop, only the references to blank values get picked up... the nonblank values pass through